# Why this code shut down the windows system?

Tags: matlab, adjacency-matrix, symmetric

I have used the following code to get the symmetric adjacency matrix from an unweighted and undirected graph.Once, i run it the windows system shut down directly

```
fidneighb2= fopen('neighborfile2.txt','rt'); 
format = repmat('%q',[1 2]);
AA = textscan(fidneighb2,format,'Delimiter', '\t');
fclose(fidneighb2);
AAneighb2= [AA{:, 1} , AA{:, 2}];
    [r,c] = size(AAneighb2);                        %# Get the matrix size
diagVec1 = repmat([ones(c-1,1); 0],r,1);  %# Make the first diagonal vector
                                          %#   (for horizontal connections)
diagVec1 = diagVec1(1:end-1);             %# Remove the last value
diagVec2 = ones(c*(r-1),1);               %# Make the second diagonal vector
                                          %#   (for vertical connections)
adj = diag(diagVec1,1)+...                %# Add the diagonals to a zero matrix
      diag(diagVec2,c);
adj = adj+adj.';                      %'# Add the matrix to a transposed
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6u8fZadKIp2TFc1c1FmNnJ3TTA

Comment: Are you saying that your computer crashed when you run this code? At which line? Is this also the case with smaller input data?

Comment: @m7913d, yes crashed, but with smaller input data worked well !

Comment: @m7913d, my input datasets are of huge size arrange from 8000 to 55135

Comment: Using a [sparse](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrix may solve your question.

Comment: Because you're performing calculations that are completely unnecessary and blowing up the size of your matrix. Please do not use code unless you understand what it's doing.